# Parsing a website data c# - HTML agility pack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I tried to parse the results from this website.
http://www.nokia.com/in-en/store-locator/?action=storeSearch&qt=madurai&tags=Nokia_Recycling_Point&country=IN

[image]

I need specifically the contents of the div class 'result-wrapper'. That is, all the 'h4', 'category' and 'description' span classes. The following is the code I could reach upto, later on, I do not know to parse that particular div. I need help to get all the contents of that div class.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            string htmlPage = "";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.nokia.com/in-en/store-locator/?action=storeSearch&qt=madurai&tags=Nokia_Recycling_Point&country=IN");
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException exc) { }
            }

        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try:

```
var resultWrapperDivs = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='result-wrapper']");
foreach (var resultWrapperDiv in resultWrapperDivs)
{
    // Do stuff with each div.
}
```

Also, to get a specific content/"html tag" you can take each `resultWrapperDiv` alone and get also its children nodes (`resultWrapperDiv.SelectSingleNode` or `resultWrapperDiv.SelectNodes`)

Comment: Thanks @shemuel. To get the child nodes, I'll have to do resultWrapperDiv.SelectNodes("h4").InnerText right ?

Comment: Yep. If you need to content of that tag. If you need the HTML content you have `InnerHtml`